# compare two columns and keep difference between strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary, replace

Before upgrading pandas from 0.25.1 to 1.1.3 , I was able to strip strings in a dataframe from this:

```
+---+------------------+------------------+
|   |   strip_me       |     pattern      |
+---+------------------+------------------+
| 0 |   string part 0  |     string       |
+---+------------------+------------------+
| 1 |   string part 1  |     part         |
+---+------------------+------------------+
```

into this:

```
+---+------------------+------------------+
|   |   strip_me       |     pattern      |
+---+------------------+------------------+
| 0 |   part 0         |     string       |
+---+------------------+------------------+
| 1 |   string 1       |     part         |
+---+------------------+------------------+
```

using an operation like this:

```
df['strip_me'] = df['strip_me'].replace(''+df.pattern,'',regex=True)
```

But since the update, my jupyter notebook returns this error:

```
ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-like to_replace and non-None value
```

What am I missing? A thorough search through stackoverflow and ggl did not provide an answer yet. I even tried to RTF-pandas-M. What approach would you take in working towards an understanding and solution to the ValueError?
I have two environments in Anaconda for debugging, one using the old pandas and one using the upgraded pandas. Downgrading is not an option due to dependencies within the stack.

I'd appreciate any help to help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a series argument is treated like a dicitonary with index being keys. The dictionary option is now available for just DataFrame. For Series, a dict `to_replace` means something else (`k:v` means replace value `k` with value `v`).

Quick fix: turn your `df['strip_me']` into a dataframe with:

```
df['strip_me'] = (df[['strip_me']].T.replace(''+df.pattern,'',regex=True)
                     .loc['strip_me']
                 )
```

Comment: I know OP had this in their sample code, but is `.replace(''+df.pattern, ...)` doing anything different than just having `.replace(df.pattern, ...)`

Comment: Your quick fix works like a charm, @quang-hoang !
Thank you for your explanation. I'll dive into your answer for a better understanding.